# PostFileWithRequest error since using Monodroid PCL

Tags: servicestack

I'm having a problem with using the Monodroid PCL libraries. All calls are working except this one:

```cs
client.PostFileWithRequest<DtoResponse>("createimage", ms, fileName, new Dto{ Id = id});
```

The error is as follows:

```cs
Object reference not set to an instance of an object at ServiceStack.Pcl.StringEqualityComparer.GetHashCode (System.String obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].get_Item (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.NameObjectCollectionBase.FindFirstMatchedItem (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseGet (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.NameValueCollection.Add (System.String name, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (System.String query, System.Text.Encoding encoding, ServiceStack.Pcl.NameValueCollection result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (System.String query, System.Text.Encoding encoding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.Pcl.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (System.String query) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.AndroidPclExportClient.ParseQueryString (System.String query) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase+<>c__DisplayClass1b`1[Lodestone.Pcl.Infrastucture.Responses.ChildImage.ChildImageResponse].<PostFileWithRequest>b__18 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.PostFileWithRequest[ChildImageResponse] (System.String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, System.IO.Stream fileToUpload, System.String fileName, System.Object request, System.String fieldName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 "
```

We didn't have this problem prior to this. We were using the 3.9.71 monodroid compiled dlls.They were not PCL. This has only stated with the v4 PCL versions.Has anyone encountered this before and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A [fix for this issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/00146335266c0da890dbf478367712b270d6d387) has been deployed to MyGet:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet

Available in the next **v4.0.16+** release on NuGet.